# ¿Cómo solucionar problemas fpdf - php en un hosting?

Tags: php, fpdf

tengo un formulario donde imprimo mis campos en un documento fpdf, estoy utilizando mvc sessiones, cuando lo hago de manera local no tengo problemas me redirige a mi nuevo pdf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de subirlo a un hosting ya no se a donde redirigirlo, mi código esta así:
-Este es el boton

```
  <button type="submit" name="btnImprimir" class="btn btn-warning" formtarget="_blank" formaction="http://localhost/mesadepartes/DocSoliSAV">IMPRIMIR Y FIRMAR</button>
```

- Mi archivo que genera el PDF

  Image('view/public/img/logo_segat.png', 20, 12, 45);
                // Arial bold 15
                $this->Cell(65, 30, '', 1, 0, 'C');
                $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 13);
- Lo trato de enviar así pero me genera problemas

  ```
  <button type="submit" name="btnImprimir" class="btn btn-warning" formtarget="_blank" formaction="https://www.truxcode.com/DocSoliQueja">IMPRIMIR Y FIRMAR</button>
  ```

Me genera este error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at /home/truxcode/public_html/controller/area.controlador.php:1)**

Comment: Alguno de los includes o algo que haces antes de generar el PDF está haciendo print, algún echo, algún error y todo eso cuenta como salida.

Comment: No puedes redirigir a `http://localhost` en el hosting y sería bueno que agregues el código que genera el PDF